# Number of leaves in a tree that represents a kind of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, trees

Consider the following rooted tree, each of whose vertices (except for the root) is labeled with an integer $\in\{1,\dots,n\}$: let $s(v)$ be the sequence consists of the labels on the path from the root to a vertex $v$ (including the label of $v$), and

1. if $s(v)$ has a decreasing subsequence, $v$ is a leaf, and
2. otherwise, $v$ has $n-|s(v)|$ children, labeled with positive integers not belonging to $s(v)$, where $|s(v)|$ is the length of $s(v)$.

The question is how many leaves this tree has.

Background: I'm analysing the sorting algorithm that examines paths from the root to every leaf.

Addendum: Sequences of length less than 2 are not decreasing.

Addendum 2: Let $r$ be the root, then $s(r)$ is the empty sequence $()$, so $r$ has $n - |s(r)|=n$ children labeled with $1,\dots,n$.

Comment: I corrected the description. I made silly mistakes because I was in a hurry.

Comment: Every sequence contains as many decreasing subsequences as it has terms, since each term by itself forms a decreasing subsequence, as does the empty subsequence. If that's not the case under your definition of a decreasing subsequence, you should provide that definition.

Comment: That's not the case; thank you for pointing out.

Comment: An alternative way to ask the same question: (a) start with all lists that are permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. (b) cut off each list after the first number that is _not_ the largest so far, (c) how many _different_ lists remain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge 2$, the sequences $s(v)$ for leaves $v$ are exactly the list $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$ plus those sequences of length $\ge 2$ without repetition where every number *except the last one* is greater than its predecessor. Once any number that is smaller than its predecessor gets added, the last two numbers in the list is a decreasing subsequence and makes the node a leaf.

(I'm assuming that you consider the bottommost $n$ node to be a leaf, rather than merely an internal node with $0$ descendants. Otherwise ignore the $+1$ in the following).

Let's count the number of qualifying sequences of length $k$, $2\le k <n$. We select $k$ numbers among $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to be in the sequence, which can be done in $\binom nk$ ways. For each choice of members, all but the largest one can come at the end of the sequence, but the other ones must appear in increasing order. So there are $(k-1)\binom nk$ lists of length $k$. For $k=n$ we can use the same expression if we remember to add $1$ to account for the list $(1,2,\ldots,n)$.

So the total number of leaves is
$$ 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)\binom nk$$
where the $k=1$ termvanishes due to the $k-1$ factor but makes the formula look slightly nicer.

Using some well-known binomial identities we can rewrite this as
$$ 2 + \sum_{k=0}^n (k-1)\binom nk = 2 + \sum_{k=0}^n k\binom nk - \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk =
2 + n2^{n-1} - 2^n = 2 + (n-2)2^{n-1}$$